# HTML5 видео в WebView

Tags: android, html5

Может кто-то сталкивался с проблемой проигрывания html5 video в webview? Рада буду любым ПОЛЕЗНЫМ ссылкам :)

Comment: вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только из вопроса непонятно какие у вас проблемы.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193684/how-to-play-html5-video-on-a-webview-android

ну и т.д.